# Can it be a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, views

[image]

Can it be a bug, or just some counters got out of sync?

Comment: It is the cache, what is confusing you!!

Comment: [See this META SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37456/invalidate-cache-when-new-question-is-posted).

Comment: @Mistu4u Thanks, but I don't think it's related. I was not asking about "newest" tab. It was about the question view.

Comment: A related [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125045/how-long-are-the-number-of-views-cached-for-search) reveals "cache" is creating discrepancies in counting "view". So it is assumable "cache" is the villain here which is  not frequently updated.However I will be looking for better explanations.

Comment: [Another Caching problem, which seems to be a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/a-user-seen-12mins-ago-but-posted-a-question-9-mins-ago-how/108662#108662)

Comment: @Mistu4u This one looks closer, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a Chicago election to me. Vote early, vote often!